# List in a custom layout page

Tags: web-part, page-layout

It seems incredible but I cannot find out **the way to add a list** ("app part") **in a page layout**.
So far I could just add a web part and then add the list manually editing the single pages created - but also in this case the **web parts are not editable** (edit panel does not appear at all).
Googleing I found that this is a common problem, but could not find workaround. Does anybody have some suggestion (for both set up a list in a page layout and/or make editable the web parts in a page layout)?
Working with SP online and SPD 2013.